# Closing (Auto)Closeables that exist only in `Either`

Tags: kotlin, either, autocloseable, arrow-kt

I currently face the problem of correctly closing resources that never leave their containing `Either`.

The relevant code looks something like this:

```
object SomeError
class MyRes : AutoCloseable { [...] }

fun createRes(): Either<SomeError, MyRes> { [...] }

fun extractData(res: MyRes): String { [...] }

fun theProblem(): Either<SomeError, String> {
    return createRes()
        .map { extractData(it) }
}
```

What is the most idiomatic way of closing the created `MyRes`? Closing it before that `map` prevents `extractData` from accessing it, and after the `map` I can't access it anymore via `Either`'s operations. Closing it in `extractData` severely limits composability.

Currently I have an external `List<AutoCloseable>` that I iterate over after all the computations, but that can't be the intended way.

I am open to using Arrow Fx (e.g. `Resource`) if that helps, but I haven't found anything on how to combine `Either` and `Resource` in an elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to combine the `either` and `Resource` safely.

```kotlin
object SomeError
class MyRes : AutoCloseable { [...] }

fun createRes(): Resource<Either<SomeError, MyRes>> { [...] }
fun extractData(res: MyRes): String { [...] }

suspend fun solution(): Either<SomeError, String> = either {
  createRes().use { either: Either<SomeError, MyRes> ->
    val res = either.bind()
    val string = extractData(res)
    // call other Either code + `bind()` safely here
    [...]

  } // <-- MyRes will automatically close here
}
```

If in this code you encounter `Either.Left` and you call `bind()` on it the `Resource` will first close, because we jump outside of *use*, and then `either` will return the encountered `Either.Left`.

Comment: Does `createRes` have to provide the release action (= the call to `close()`) when creating the resource, or are there special implementation that handle that automatically? Also, this does not completely cover my problem, since this still moves the resource handling _outside_ the either chain.

Comment: You can use `Resource.fromAutoCloseable { MyRes() }` and that can automatically close resource for any type `A : AutoCloseable`.

A similar constructor exists for `Closeable` and otherwise, you can manually specify the `close`/`shutdown` through the regular constructor.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense than my intuition of a specialization for `Either`. I've tried your suggestion and it works and is fine for my current use case. I was hoping (my question is not worded very well) to find a solution for more complex cases (think `String->HTTPRequest->String`, where the `AutoCloseable` never exists outside the `Either`-`map`-chain), but I guess I'll have to break those up into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution I found was wrapping the block passed to `map`:

```
fun <B : AutoCloseable, C> andClose(f: (B) -> C): (B) -> C =
    { b: B -> b.use { f(b) } }


fun theProblemSlightlySolved(): Either<SomeError, String> {
    return createRes()
        .map(andClose { extractData(it) })
}
```

Comment: Which `createRes()` function do you use here?

Comment: `createRes()` is of type `() -> Either<SomeError, AutoCloseable>`.